# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '04/10/2014 2:21PM'

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to update the value for column 'fromDate' i get this error in server.please help in fixing this issue

Comment: what is the data type of ur fromDate and how ur query looks like ?

Comment: datatype is datetime and query is like update tablename set fromDate=?

Comment: Show us the table definition and the exact statement that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date format for date time field in mysql should be like '2014-04-10 14:21:00'

You can use below update query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET FromDate=STR_TO_DATE('04/10/2014 2:21:00PM','%c/%e/%Y %r') WHERE id=123;
```

---

If it always will be in this format then you can try below query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET FromDate=STR_TO_DATE(IF(RIGHT('04/10/2014 2:21PM',2)='PM',REPLACE('04/10/2014 2:21PM','PM',':00PM'),REPLACE('04/10/2014 2:21AM','AM',':00AM')),'%c/%e/%Y %r') WHERE id=123;
```

Comment: Data will be stored in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format you can show in any format in your query as per your requirement.

Comment: so how to give this in update query as from front end i get in this format 04/10/2014 2:21PM

Comment: thanks zafar but my time format in front end is 2:21pm it does not iinclude seconds

Comment: If it always will be in this format then you can try the new query in my answer.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('04/10/2014 2:21PM','PM',':00PM'),'%c/%e/%Y %r')

Comment: Please use newone I edited my query as this will take care only PM but what about if AM, so use query which I updated in my answer, which will take care to both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

[**mysql datetime format**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html)

```
Update tableName set fromdate = '2014-10-01 14:21:00' where "condition"
```

To format the date as you want :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`fromDate`, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%p') as fromDate
from tableName;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c22ec/8)**

Comment: While retrieving from database, format accordingly. Mysql keeps datetime in this format only.

Comment: but in front end i get in this format 04/10/2014 2:21PM then what has to be done

Comment: Are you getting from date in this format now? or do you want to get in this format?

Comment: actually from front end i am getting like this 04/10/2014 2:21PM no seconds in front end . how to update in sql format

Comment: update tablename set fromdate='04/10/2014 2:21 PM' where condition=?

Comment: Please show the query you used to export data. Above query is for updating